# Android 4.4.3 update, dialer add 2 second pause - what is it?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app

THe new dialer for android 4.4.3 has an option for "add 2 second pause" and "add wait". What do these options do?

I'll add a screenshot soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It adds a delay to the buttons you dial when it is dialing. It is for interactive request on the phone (E.g. Press 1 to speak to RossC)

Here's an example that might explain it:

Say you do the following to top up your phone credit:

> Dial 1741
>
> Select option 1 for top up
>
> Select Option 2 for enter code
>
> Enter 20 digit code (XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX)

You could simply dial:

`1741 <ADD 2 SECOND PAUSE> 1 <ADD 2 SECOND PAUSE> 2 <ADD 2 SECOND PAUSE> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`  and it will all process. It literally adds a pause of 2 seconds to the buttons it dials!

My ancient Nokia phone used to have a 'P' for this above the # key. So you would have had 1741 P 1 p 2 etc on it. Very convenient for something you regularly call.

Comment: Ha! that explains that. I have never used this functionality. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common on phone (and previously modem) diallers. You can use it to get through caller menu systems (the "press 1 for something, press 2 for something else" type menus) also known as [Interactive voice response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response) systems.

It's not normally shown as a menu option in the phone's dialler but you can normally enter a comma `,` into a dialler to get a short pause. You can then save this phone number along with all the number presses after it as a contact in your phone.

I have a contact saved in my mobile phone that calls my work voicemail system, waits a couple of seconds, then enters my PIN, then waits another couple of seconds, then presses "1" to hear new voicemails, this lets me do everything I need to do to listen to my messages with one click. It looks a bit like this:

```
020 1234 5678,,1234#,1
```

*(the number at the start is the number that's called, the commas are the pauses, and everything after the first pause is used to get through  the menus)*

When I dealt regularly dealt with the customer services parts of other companies, I had the details saved as a contact on my phone to get all the way through their phone menu system to a real human being with one phone call.